# How to get textContent from a <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a greasemonkey script to format some raw numbers by thousands. The format function is just fine. Problem is: some numbers are placed on img tags, for instance:

```
<div class = "opinion">
    <img class ="icon-like" alt="img" src="like.png">1148597
    <img class="icon-dislike" alt="img" src="dislike.png">600000000
</div>
```

Since img tags by definition [has no child nodes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/hasChildNodes), what is the best way to iterate over the imgs to place the formatted number back on them? If I use .innerHTML, the img tag is removed, displaying just the formatted numbers.

tnx in advance.

Comment: As you said img tags has no child nodes, so it cannot have textContent. In you example those numbers are the nextSibling node(text nodes) of the img elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling) on the image, then use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) to actually get the text:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.opinion img');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function (el) {
    var text = el.nextSibling.textContent;
    // Use the text associated with the image...
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TYGAq/